# Error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noun' of undefined** while fetching data from json

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to fetch data from url, but I am facing an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noun' of undefined**,

Can anyone tell me why this error is appearing?

https://codepen.io/Thakur92411/pen/bZMObY?editors=1011

```js
var googlelink = "https://googledictionaryapi.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/?define=apple&lang=en";

$.getJSON(googlelink, linkdata);

function linkdata(worddata) {
  console.log(worddata.meaning.noun.defination[0])
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/3082296)

Answer (score 0):

`worddata` and `noun` are not objects. They are both arrays. Use

```
worddata[0].meaning.noun[0].definition
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
let googlelink = "https://googledictionaryapi.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/?define=apple&lang=en";

function linkdata(worddata) {
  console.log(worddata[0].meaning.noun)
  console.log(worddata[0].meaning.noun[0].definition)
}

$.getJSON(googlelink, linkdata);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Everything looks good, the only problem is that you are not reading the response correctly. Once see the below code for your reference.

```
apiLink = "https://googledictionaryapi.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/?define=apple&lang=en";
$.ajax({
  "url": apiLink,
    success: function(response){
    console.log(response[0].meaning.noun[0].definition);
  }
});
```

Comment: How is this different than the answer which is already posted? Please don't add extra noise.